# Using Entity Framework to filter by columns in constrained tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

My application uses asp.net 4, C# and Entity Framework. My database contains a table `Companies` which has many `Locations`, which in turn has many `Devices`. A `Company` is keyed to the aspnet_user which is currently logged in.

I use grid views to display and edit the `Locations` and `Devices` for a single `Company`. This is easily achieved for the `Locations` as they have a direct link to a `Company`...

```
LocationListEntityDataSource.AutoGenerateWhereClause = true;
LocationListEntityDataSource.WhereParameters.Clear();
LocationListEntityDataSource.WhereParameters.Add("CompanyGuid", System.Data.DbType.Guid, Tools.Tools.getCompanyGuidString());
```

However I can not work out how to filter the `Devices` by `Company` as they only have a link to a `Location`. I had hope to use something similar to the following, but I get an exception stating that `Location.CompanyGuid` could not be found...

```
DeviceListEntityDataSource.AutoGenerateWhereClause = true;
DeviceListEntityDataSource.WhereParameters.Clear();
DeviceListEntityDataSource.WhereParameters.Add("Location.CompanyGuid", System.Data.DbType.Guid, Tools.Tools.getCompanyGuidString());
```

Any ideas on how this can be achieved?

Comment: This less of an entity framework question and more of a modelling/schema question. You should retag (e.g. remove [tag:asp.net] which is irrelevent and add [tag:database-schema]) and add a diagram of your current schema and of your entities.

Comment: Can you describe or most minimal version of models? In your case why not Company have one to many relationship with Locations as well as Devices. Like to add a device first create a Location. Then `location.Devices.Add(device`). And then `dbconext.Companies.Add(location);`

Comment: "why not Company have one to many relationship with Locations as well as Devices"- I assume that you mean Devices as well as Locations? I had considered this, but there are many other tables which are also linked to a Location. To save on space I wanted to avoid linking a huge number of tables to a Company as I assumed that the company could be inferred from the location

Comment: When you put a virtual property of `ICollection<Device> Devices` to the `Company` class. This will be just a navigation property. This will not create any column in company table for Devices. Then you have virtual property `Company comapany` and FK `int CompanyId` in the Device model. This will only add one field to Device table which is not big wastage of space.

Comment: Thanks Abhijit, I guess I'll just bite the bullet and key all of the relevant tables to the Company then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider Company to have one to many relationship with Locations as well as Devices.

When you put a virtual property of `ICollection<Device> Devices;` to the `Company class`. This will be just a navigation property. This will not create any column in company table for Devices. Then you have virtual property Company comapany and FK int CompanyId in the Device model. This will only add one field to `Device` table which is not big wastage of space.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the Devices can be filtered by Company by manually binding the data using the following code:

```
      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
           (SalesSQLEntities db = new SalesSQLEntities())
           {
                // Get user ID
                System.Guid UserID = Tools.Tools.getCompanyGuid();

                // Find all transactions of this company
                var devItemList = (from dev in db.Devices
                                       where dev.Location.CompanyGuid == UserID
                                       select dev).ToList();

                DeviceList.DataSource = devItemList;
                DeviceList.DataBind();
            }
      }
```

I would suggest that this is a better design than creating direct links between tables which already have indirect links.

Less links result in simpler maintenance, smaller database (negligible), and clearer diagrams.

Any objections?